# Adding a control button for a form for a query built in the VS 2010 query builder

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Double part question...

I have built several queries for a MS Access database in VS 2010 Express. However I am having trouble attaching the queries to control buttons on a form.  Is the only way to manually call the method generated by the query builder in the code section or is there a short cut.

Also, I am trying to update fields in a query and my SQL code keeps getting rejected by the builder by saying unable to parse text. The fields are "double" values here is the SQL - any help is greatly appreciated:

```
UPDATE STUDENT
SET [student_Grade] = CASE 
                         WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [90] AND [100] THEN 'A' 
                         WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [80] AND [89] THEN 'B' 
                         WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [70] AND [79] THEN 'C' 
                         WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [60] AND [69] THEN 'D' 
                         WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [1] AND [59] THEN 'F' 
                      END;
```

This code is supposed to change the grade field when the average is updated with new grades that are entered

Comment: Is this an MS-Access form, or a form on some sort of web page?

Answer (score 0):

so , you couldn't update the fields in varchar type,because the field "student_Grade" is double , if you just wanna display this grade's to string type like 'A,B,C',please don't update it,is not logic, you may show it in a SELECT query and query like this,

```
SELECT student_grade, grade_Level = CASE 
WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [90] AND [100] THEN 'A' 
WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [80] AND [89] THEN 'B' 
WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [70] AND [79] THEN 'C' 
WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [60] AND [69] THEN 'D' 
WHEN [student_Avg] BETWEEN [1] AND [59] THEN 'F' END
FROM Student
```